# Prove that $ \int_{-1}^0f(x)dx=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb D}f(z)\log (z)dz $.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a function holomorphic in the open unit disc $\mathbb D:=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon |z|<1\}$ and continuous in the closure $\overline{\mathbb D}$. Prove that
>   $$ \int_{-1}^0f(x)dx=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb D}f(z)\log (z)dz $$ where $\log(z)$ is the branch of the logarithm function which is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus\{(-\infty, 0]\}$ with $\log (1)=0$.

---

My attempt:

Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ since $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$. Then since $f(z)\log(z)$ is uniformly continuous on $\partial\mathbb D\setminus\{-1\}$, we have:
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb D}f(z)\log (z)dz&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{\partial\mathbb D}z^n\log(z)dz\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta}i\theta e^{i\theta} id\theta\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{-\pi}^\pi -e^{i(n+1)\theta}\theta d\theta.
\end{align}
Integrating by parts, we get:
$$ -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb D}f(z)\log (z)dz=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{a_n}{n+1}.$$

Likewise, since $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb D}$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{-1}^0 z^ndz\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{a_n}{n+1}
\end{align}
And we are done.

---

Is my proof correct? Now I am curious if there are other methods without using power series. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. Another approach is by performing integration by parts on the right hand side:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\partial\mathbb D}f(z)\log (z)dz
&=\left[F(z)\log z\right]^{e^{\pi i}}_{e^{-\pi i}}-\underbrace{\int_{\partial\mathbb D}\frac{F(z)}zdz}_{=0} \qquad{(*)}\\
&=F(-1)(\pi i)-F(-1)(-\pi i)\\
&=2\pi iF(-1) \\
&=2\pi i\int^{-1}_0f(z)dz \\
&=-2\pi i\int_{-1}^0f(z)dz \\
\end{align}
$$

$(*)$: $\displaystyle{F(z):=\int^z_0 f(z)dz}$. Since $F(0)=0$ and $F$ is holomorphic, the singularity of $\frac{F(z)}z$ at $0$ is removable, and the contour integral is zero by residue theorem.